# Reverse PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql

Here is code code Im Working With:

```
<?php

function get_gold_time_noformat()


{
     $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
    WHERE metal = 'GOLD' ORDER BY  `metal_price`.`time` DESC 
) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 16 = 1 
LIMIT 6
");

         while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) 
 { 

    echo "<div id=\"dates\">" . date('g a', strToTime($result['time'] . ' - 7 hours')) .  "</div>";   
 } 

         }
?>
```

I am simply trying to reverse the array, I tried using array_reverse but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Wow, your function is called `get_gold_time_noformat` yet it doesn't return anything, but prints to screen. That's confusing.

Comment: It returns the time from my Database, I have it set to skip every 16 rows ( 4 hours) so that I can print the last 24 hours from the latest scraped time. Unfortunately I am having trouble reversing the order of these displayed times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array reverse will work if you use it on an array.

```
<?php
function get_gold_time_noformat() {
    $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
        FROM ( 
            SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
            WHERE metal = 'GOLD' ORDER BY  `metal_price`.`time` DESC 
        ) ranked 
        WHERE rownum % 16 = 1 
        LIMIT 6"
    );

    $array_result = array();

    while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) { 
        $array_result[] = $result;
    }

    $array_result = array_reverse( $array_result );

    foreach( $array_result as $result ) {
        echo "<div id=\"dates\">" . date('g a', strToTime($result['time'] . ' - 7 hours')) .  "</div>";   
    } 
}
?>
```

Although I suggest seeing if you can reverse it in the SQL.

Comment: It Returned this Error:   Fatal error: Call to undefined function arra() in /home/bellsnet/public_html/chart.php on line 196

Answer (score 2):

Don't use PHP. Use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
        WHERE metal = 'GOLD' ORDER BY  `metal_price`.`time` DESC 
    ) ranked 
    WHERE rownum % 16 = 1 
    ORDER BY rownum DESC
    LIMIT 6
```